# Zip ByteArray decompression returns null but input stream is valid

Tags: java, file, csv, kotlin, compression

So i am trying to zip a csv file in memory, store it as a BLOB in MYSQL and then fetch and decompress it, but the ZipInputStream.getEntry returns null and i really can't decompress the file, i tried everything and i really can't find the answer.
First time i compressed/decompressed the file using GZIP and worked, but it altered the CSV file structure so thats why i am trying with Zip.
The CSV file is recieved from the front end via Spring's MultipartFile.getBytes().

Here is the compressed file header seen from DB 
(The header seems valid)

```
00000000  50 4B 03 04 14 00 08 08 08 00 B4 A0 8F 50 00 00    PK........´ .P..
```

Thanks in advance!

The compression method:

```
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun compressFile(file : ByteArray) : ByteArray {
    val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val zos = ZipOutputStream(baos)
    val entry = ZipEntry("data.csv")
    entry.size = file.size.toLong()
    zos.putNextEntry(entry)
    zos.write(file)
    zos.closeEntry()
    zos.close()
    return baos.toByteArray()
}
```

The decompression method:

```
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun decompressFile(file : ByteArray): ByteArray {
   if (file.isEmpty()) return file
   val gis = ZipInputStream(ByteArrayInputStream(file))
   val bf = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(gis, "UTF-8"))
   var outStr = ""
   var line: String
   while (bf.readLine().also { line = it ?: "" } != null) {
       outStr += line
   }
   gis.close()
   bf.close()
   return outStr.toByteArray()
}
```

[The ZipInputStream object after init](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5V4xu.png)

Comment: You never call `getNextEntry()`, so which zip entry do you believe you are reading?

Comment: @Andreas I dont need to call getNextEntry because i read directly from the stream (at least GZIP worked this way), but i also tried the getNetEntry and it returrned null, you can check the image i linked below with the created ZipInputStream object.

Comment: GZIP is not ZIP. --- No idea what the image shows. Is that the state before or after you called `getNextEntry()`?

Comment: @Andreas ok then, so how can i decompress the file as a byte array if the ZipInputStream entry is null?

Comment: @Andreas or at least why does the GZIP alters my CSV file? The file before compressing with gzip is
header1,header2,header3
*new line*
val1,val2,val3

after compression -> 
header1,header2,header3val1,val2,val3

Comment: GZIP doesn't alter the file. --- To read first file from a zip file, call `getNextEntry()` *then* start reading the bytes.

Comment: @Andreas thanks! it works

Comment: Yeah, it works exactly like I said [from the beginning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61234935/zip-bytearray-decompression-returns-null-but-input-stream-is-valid?noredirect=1#comment108329179_61234935): you didn't call `getNextEntry()`, so no data was returned.

Comment: @Vlad Look at your code blocks and remove the backticks. You need them to escape code _inside text_, not in a separate block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read a `ZipInputStream`, you must call `getNextEntry()` before reading.

For this example, I created a zip file with 2 files:

- `foo.text` with content `Foo Bar`
- `hello.txt` with content `Hello World`

Here is code to show that attempting to read before calling `getNextEntry()` will yield nothing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try (ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:\\Temp\\foo.zip"))) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(zip, "UTF-8"));

        // read before getNextEntry() finds nothing
        printText(reader);

        ZipEntry zipEntry;
        while ((zipEntry = zip.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Entry Name: " + zipEntry.getName() + "   Size: " + zipEntry.getSize());

            // read after getNextEntry() finds only the entry's content
            printText(reader);
        }
    }
}
static void printText(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException {
    int count = 0;
    for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; count++)
        System.out.println("  " + line);
    System.out.println(count + " lines");
}
```

*Output*

```
0 lines
Entry Name: foo.txt   Size: 7
  Foo Bar
1 lines
Entry Name: hello.txt   Size: 11
  Hello World
1 lines
```

Comment: It works! i assumed that if "entry" property is null in the object and entry size is -1 the data isn't being read properly. But now i am back at the problem i had with GZIP, i have a CSV that initially is header1,header2,heeader3 (new line) val1, val2, val3 (new line) val4,val5,val6 (standard csv format, first line column headers and then the rows) but after the compression the file is  header1,header2,heeader3val1, val2, val3val4,val5,val6 (no new lines, and I cant remake the file as it was/

Comment: @Vlad This question was about `ZipInputStream` and has been answered. If you have a problem with GZIP, that's a different problem, so create a new question, and include a [`Minimal, Reproducible Example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) proving your assertion that it changes the content, and that it's not *your* code doing it. --- Only one question/problem per question.